# Rails: show name instead of Id in a show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two tables, `accounts` and `items` and I would like to `show` the `buisness_name` instead of the `id`from the accounts table on the `view/items/show.html.erb` page.

Currently I have no associations between the models, but I have the `account_id` column in the `items` table.

```
 create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "buisness_name"
    t.string "web_site"
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end

create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "image"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.json "attachments"
    t.integer "account_id"
end
```

I'm getting the `account_id` via this: `<%= @item.account_id %>`, but I would like to show the `buisness_name` instead.

Comment: JFYI, it's "business", not "buisness"

Comment: "Currently I have no associations between the models" - that's what you need to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account 
end
```

Into the view

```
<% if @item.account %>
  <%= @item.account.buisness_name %>
<% end %>
```

Should be `business_name`, as @Sergio Tulentsev already told you

I updated my answer because I noticed from the table that the `account_id` has not a `not null` constraint

Answer (score 2):

If you have

```
<%= @item.account_id %>
```

The horrible way to get the account would be

```
<%= Account.find_by(id: @item.account_id).try(:buisness_name) %>
```

Much smarter would be

```
class Item

  belongs_to :account

  delegate :buisness_name, to: :account, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
```

And then in the view...

```
<%= @item.account_buisness_name %>
```

Comment: Might want to use `prefix: true` on that delegate. Items don't usually have business names. :)

Comment: you could also do `@item.account.try(:bussiness_name)` which is pretty clean. The delegate solution works fine, but if you catch yourself in need of multiple scenarios like this and lots of conditions inside the view, you might want to check what a `decorator` is. The draper gem (https://github.com/drapergem/draper) is a good start.